# Show only a part of SlidingDrawer?

Tags: android

I want to have the SlidingDrawer show in 2 parts. On the first swipe up it shows only 1 button. and in the other swipe up, it shows the second button.
How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could always have a counter in the SlidingDrawer that counts how many times the user have opened the drawer. And depending on the counter you either choose another layout or just use 
setVisibility on different views.

Simple example, lets say you have button1 the first time the user opens the drawer and button2 the second time. If the user draws it a third time set the counter to 0 again.

```
if(counter==0) {
 button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 button2.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
}
else {
 button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

[SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)
For the counter you could use [setOnDrawerCloseListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html#setOnDrawerCloseListener%28android.widget.SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerCloseListener%29) to change the value since you want to have the upcoming counter value before the user have opened the drawer.

Comment: The slidingDrawer is set to wrap_content. when it shows the first button only, it takes a third of the screen which is good.. now what I want to do is to show the second button if the user swipes up again.. and close it if he swipes down.

Comment: Yes, and I gave you an answer on how to do that.